# Castle Windsor: Typed Factory not using registered sub resolver

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have created simple factory:

```
public interface ICommandFactory
{
    ICommand CreateCommand(string componentName);
}
```

Implemented using Typed Factory feature from Windsor:

```
Container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
Container.Kernel.Register(Component.For<ICommandFactory>().AsFactory());
```

also i am using subresolver:

```
Container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CommandResolverByName(Container.Kernel, null));
```

Unfortunately when i try to use typed factory for my interface it doesn't use custom subresolver.
Does anyone one know this problem or is it just the way typed factory works :>

Thanks in advance

Jakub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does in version 2.5.